# ActivatedRoute.routeConfig is null - Angular 2 project with Angular-cli

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular-cli, routeconfig

I have created 2 different projects using `angular-cli`. Both work perfectly but in one of them `routeConfig` is `null` and have no idea what's wrong.

The `package.json` of both file are the same so there's no any doubt about packages versions, `app.modules` files are the same as well.

Here is how I get `routeConfig` in both projects :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private router: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.router.routeConfig);
  }
}
```

what's wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggles and looking around my code, I found the major difference between the two apps, which it was in the template part.

When works :home.component.html

```
<div class="container bg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <div class="content-bar">
        <!-- Body -->
        <p>
          home works!
        </p>
        <!-- /body -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When doesn't work : app.component.html

```
<div class="container bg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <!-- <app-sidebar></app-sidebar> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <div class="content-bar">
        <!-- Body -->
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <!-- /body -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**It should be noted that** `ActivatedRoute` was `NULL` inside `sidebar.component.ts`.

If the answer is not clear enough, feel free to mention in comments, I will update it.

**Update:** As [@alterfox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47248704/activatedroute-routeconfig-is-null-angular-2-project-with-angular-cli/47257276?noredirect=1#comment92322778_47257276)'s request the following explanation has been provided :

When I call `<app-sidebar>` in the same `xxx.component.html` as  `<router-outlet>` is called, `routeConfig` doesn't get any value, so I changed my code as mentioned and moved `<app-sidebar>` to a level deeper inside `home.component.html` which means I had to call it in every `xxx.component.html`

Comment: From the given example, I cannot determine what the exact issue was/is. Can you please share your conclusions?

Comment: Thanks for the update! So you needed to have a common sidebar inside each component instead of in app.component, in order to have `routerConfig` available in AppComponent's `activatedRoute`?

Comment: @alterfox That's true, I don't really know if there are better ways to do that. Btw, this way it works great in production, the only problem is rewriting the code.